# Windows 8.1 Partition not visible in ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04

While configuring the partitions in installation of ubuntu, it didn't show any of the partitions I have made in 8.1, neither primary or logical drive nor unallocated space of 50GB (made for ubutu).

How to make windows partitions visible in Ubuntu installation & will 50GB space be sufficient for proper functioning of ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your grub is not updated. Log in to ubuntu and fire command `sudo update-grub` and/or `sudo update-grub2`

Comment: Thanks vishal. But i am very new at ubuntu & trying to install it. So can you please guide me about how to fire these commands without ubuntu installed (i have bootable pendrive of ubuntu) ????

Comment: Which OS has been installed on your device?

Comment: Currentĺy i have windows 8.1 and want to install ubuntu 14.04. But whïle installation, in partition configuration this problem came (No windows partitions were visibĺe, only single partition of whoĺe harddisk was there.) So now how to fire command in ubuntu???

Comment: This happened because you selected entire HD as a install partition. While installation select "Do Something Else".

Comment: Yup i had selected  something else. After that partitîon manager opened in installation wizard. But it did nt show windows partitions.